# Generate a path in a 2d matrix in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a `ReactJs` application and I have a 2d matrix. I need to generate a random path from a starting cell to an end cell given the number of rows and columns.

I found this code that calculate the number of paths possible, but I need the paths themselves.

Here is the code

```
function findMaxPath(currentRow, currentColumn, destRow, destCol) {
  // Base condition
  if (currentRow > destRow || currentColumn > destCol) {
    return 0;
  }
  // Successful path found
  if (currentRow === destRow && currentColumn === destCol) {
     return 1;
  }
  // Finding the number of paths that can be formed from increasing
  // the current row's Count and Current column's count one after the other.
  const pathsInRows = findMaxPath(currentRow + 1, currentColumn, destRow, destCol);
  const pathsInColums = findMaxPath(currentRow, currentColumn + 1, destRow, destCol);
  return (pathsInRows + pathsInColums);
}


function findMaxPathSrcToDes(rows, cols) {
  // Initial rows and columns to begin with.0,0 is the first row and col index we are choosing
  return findMaxPath(0, 0, rows - 1, cols - 1);
}

const num_of_paths = findMaxPathSrcToDes(3, 3);
console.log('Number of Paths', num_of_paths);
```

How can I get the paths?

The rules for this algorithm is:

- I only need one path, it can change everytime
- The starting point is always bottom-left, and the destination point is top-right
- the path should go UP or LEFT or RIGHT (not U-turns)
- The returned result can have this format  [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1]]

EDIT:

[image]

**Desired type of paths:**

[image]

Comment: You need *all* paths or one random path?

Comment: Just one path @trincot

Comment: Also: that code will keep the paths within the bounding box of the two coordinates. Is this what you want, or can the random path go outside of that bounding box? For instance, if a=(2,2) and b=(4,4), can the path from a to b include (1,3)?

Comment: @trincot I will always go from bottom left to top right

Comment: From the question: _but I need the paths themselves_ and _How can I get the paths?_. On the comment above: _Just one path_. Which is it? All paths or just one. If it is just one, do you need the function to return a different path each time it is called - or is it okay to return the same path every time it is called? Also, could you please share the expected result - like is it a string (like `0,0 - 0,1 - 0,2 - 1,2` - to reach from `0,0` to `1,2`) - or should it be an array? Will there be a starting-point and an ending-point? May the path include diagonal moves - like from `0,0` to `1,1`?

Comment: I can keep all paths and everytime I return a random one.

Comment: Can a path make U-turns, like (0,0)-(1,0)-(2,0)-(2,1)-(2,2)-(1,2)-(1,1)-(0,1)-(0,2)-(0,3)-...etc

Comment: @jsN00b The result can be and array of arrays, example: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1]] ...

Comment: @trincot No it can't have U-turns

Comment: So, I think a few important restrictions are missing from the question. Please edit your question, and describe exactly what the rules are.

Comment: I will add the rule

Comment: @trincot Take a look please

Comment: If the path can go left and right, then this would be ok: (0,0)-(0,1)-(0,2)-(1,2)-(1,1)-(1,0)-(2,0)-...etc, meaning that the length of the path can vary... it can zig-zag, which would certainly look like a U-turn. And this kind of path would not get counted by the function you provided. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242852/discussion-between-amine-and-trincot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need one path, it would require too much memory to generate them all. Instead consider that it is known how many "moves" will be vertical, as they can only go up. If there are *n* rows in the matrix, then there will be *n-1* up moves.

These up-moves can occur at any column, independent of the row. So the randomness lies in the selection of the column where the up-move will occur. If we have *n* numbers which each represent a column, then we have uniquely defined a path. It can be built from that information.

Here is an implementation, where the starting point is always at the bottom row, at a given X-coordinate, and the ending point is always at the top row, at a given X-coordinate:

```js
function randint(range) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}

function randomPath(sizeX, sizeY, startX, endX) {
    let x = startX;
    let path = [];
    for (let y = sizeY - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        let upX = y ? randint(sizeX) : endX;
        while (x != upX) {
            path.push([x, y]);
            if (x < upX) x++;
            else x--;
        }
        path.push([x, y]);
    }
    // Remove U-turns
    for (let i = path.length - 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i+3 < path.length && path[i][1] === path[i+3][1] + 1 && path[i][0] === path[i+3][0]) {
            path.splice(i+1, 2); // Remove U
        }
    }
    return path;
}

function displayPath(sizeX, sizeY, path) {
    let grid = Array.from({length: sizeY}, () => Array(sizeX).fill("."));
    for (let [x, y] of path) {
        grid[y][x] = "X";
    }
    console.log(grid.map(row => row.join(" ")).join("\n"));
}

// Let's do this for a 7x7 matrix:
let sizeX = 7, sizeY = 7;
let path = randomPath(sizeX, sizeY, 2, 4); // Start at X=2 at bottom, end at X=4 at top
console.log(JSON.stringify(path));
displayPath(sizeX, sizeY, path);
```

When the first part of the code generates a U-turn, it will be a sequence of left-up-right or right-up-left. So for example: [3,0],[2,0],[2,1],[3,1] is a U turn. It can be seen that the first and last point are 1 y-unit apart. These points have 2 other points between them, so on the path they have a distance of 3.

The second part of the code will look for cases where points that are 3 steps apart on the path, have the same X coordinate and 1 unit of difference on the Y coordinate. If such an instance is found, the two points between them (which represent the turn) are cut out of the path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's fast and accurate, but I think we misunderstood the logic wanted, I would love to go from a specific point to a specific point. Also I will add an image of a generated path that doesn't meet the specification I provided in the question

Comment: Please take a look at the desired type of paths in the question edit

Comment: OK, so, the coordinate [0, 0] is not where you want to start? That is confusing, because you wrote *"The returned result can have this format [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1]]"*. Do I get it right that the path should start at [n, 0], where n is the last row? You write here *"specific point"*: what is it? In the question you write *"The starting point is always bottom-left, and the destination point is top-right"*. Is that not true anymore? Why in the last image (desired), are there two different colors? Why does the path not end in the top-right corner? What's the blue circle on the red image?

Comment: It's always true, but as you see the 0, 0 is in top in my case. The ending point is not so important (In the example of code i provided in the question, I can put the start and ending point). In your code I removed `if (x < upX) x++;
            else x--;` and just put `x++`, it's giving a usable path as I need but it would be nice if I can choose the points of start and end

Comment: In the desired path I provided, different colors because next step I will choose random cases from the generated path.

Comment: So, I don't need to pay attention to the colors then? Also, what did you want to highlight in the image with the red path? Is there anything wrong with the circled cells?

Comment: Yeah that's it colors doesn't matter. In the red colored cells image, there is U-turns, which is not accepted.

Comment: So are you saying that an UP must always be followed by another UP? Or is it just LEFT UP RIGHT and RIGHT UP LEFT sequences that are not allowed? You should really clarify this rule in your question.

Comment: Assuming that is what you want, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit your approach? Especially how you removed the u-turns

Comment: Added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING**: This answer may not be 100% accurate or complete

Please use this as a reference to build and refine further to obtain the solution that will be suited for the question.

```js
const n = 3;

const getAllPaths = ({sr, sc, tr, tc, idx, arr, obj}) => {
//console.log('sr, sc: ', sr, sc, '\narr: ', arr);
  if (sr > tr || sc > tc) return false;
  if (sr === tr && sc === tc) {
    return ({
      obj: {
        ...obj,
        [idx + 1]: [...arr]
      },
      idx: idx + 1
    })
  };
  const rowRes = getAllPaths({
    sr: sr + 1, sc, tr, tc, idx, arr: arr.concat([[sr+1, sc]]), obj: {...obj}
  });
  //console.log('rowRes: ', rowRes);
  const colRes = getAllPaths({
    sr, sc: sc + 1, tr, tc,
    arr: arr.concat([[sr, sc+1]]),
    idx: rowRes ? rowRes.idx : idx,
    obj: rowRes ? {...rowRes.obj} : {...obj}
  });
  //console.log('colRes: ', colRes);
  return colRes ? {...colRes} : {idx, obj: {...obj}}
};

const getAllPathsSrcDest = (rows = n, cols = n) => getAllPaths(
  {sr: 0, sc: 0, tr: rows - 1, tc: cols - 1, idx: -1, arr: [[0,0]], obj: {}}
);

const allPaths = getAllPathsSrcDest()?.obj;
const renderNicely = obj => Object
  .entries(obj || {})
  .map(
    ([k,v]) => (`path num: ${+k+1} path: ${v.join(' - ')}`)
  );
console.log(renderNicely(allPaths));

const userInput = prompt('Enter matrix size 3, 4, 5, etc: ');
console.log('userInput: ', userInput);
console.log(
  renderNicely(
    getAllPathsSrcDest(userInput, userInput)?.obj
  )
);
```

**Explanation**

- Use a similar approach as shown in OP's question
- Instead of simply counting each way, track the exact path
- The variables `idx`, `arr` and `obj` are used to identify and capture valid paths.

**Known Issues**

- The list of paths is not complete. There are paths that are missing.
- There is no `random`-ization - so, the exact same list of paths are returned
- May explore option/s to `memo`-ize the solution and `random`-ize the value being returned on each call

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it's well done. BUT I need the random factor in the algorithm. Can you please adjust the algorithm.

Comment: Please use @trincot's answer - it is so much more efficient for this purpose.